# MVC 5 Highcjarts ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I'm trying to load the data into simple Highcharts by Ajax call. In the controller I have :

```
public ActionResult GetDailyOutput()
    {
        string result = repository.GetGraphData("spCTGetDailyOutput");

        return Json(result);
    }
```

and my View looks like that:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetDailyOutput", "Highcharts")', function (data) {
            options.series[0].data = data;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
</script>
```

So the controller have value result = "[[1,12],[2,5],[3,18],[4,13],[5,7],[6,4],[7,9],[8,10],[9,15],[10,22]]"

But the chart doesn't contain any data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check below code. Here is working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ar886smr/

I used `$.parseJSON()` to parse incoming string of array of arrays to JS Array.

```
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetDailyOutput", "Highcharts")', function (data) {                
               $('#container').highcharts({
                 series: [{
                    name: 'Name',
                    data: $.parseJSON(data)
                  }]
               });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {   

$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetDailyOutput", "Highcharts")', function (data) {
     var dataForChart = data;
     var options = {
       chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
         type: 'spline'
       },
       series: [{data: dataForChart}]
     };

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure if this is enough when it comes to HighCharts (maybe also You need to set up the type of chart (it goes to "series", above "data"); maybe the Y/X-axis as well).